# how to get content from div container with two class names (imdb)

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

Excuse my English.

everybody,

I get a white page when I try to query the content in the DIV container of the URL.

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature,tv_movie&release_date=,2018'); //get the html returned from the following url

$doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

if(!empty($html)){ //if any html is actually returned

    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    //get all the h2's with an id
    $row = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 'lister-item-image') and contains(@class, 'float-left')]/a");

    if($row->length > 0){
        foreach($row as $row){
            echo $row->nodeValue . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

The content can be found within this DIV´s .

```
<div class="lister-item-image float-left">


<a href="/title/tt1502407/?ref_=adv_li_i"
> <img alt="Halloween"
class="loadlate"
loadlate="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMmMzNjJhYjUtNzFkZi00MWQ4LWJiMDEtYWM0NTAzNGZjMTI3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyOTE2OTMwNDk@._V1_UX67_CR0,0,67,98_AL_.jpg"
data-tconst="tt1502407"
height="98"
src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/imdb/images/nopicture/large/film-184890147._CB470041630_.png"
width="67" />
</a>        </div>
```

I mainly want to query the name, link, genre and length. And a maximum of 50 should be displayed and a link "Next" the next 50 should be queried.

I thank you in advance for possible help.

Comment: So, what's wrong here? Are you retrieving the HTML? Is your XPath returning any nodes? Do your nodes have anything useful in `nodeValue`? Do some basic troubleshooting and error checking to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I'm not getting any feedback at all.  I only receive a white page.  Unfortunately I don't know why.

For other pages the code works, only for imdb it causes problems.

Comment: Then I would suggest creating some feedback. Put some debugging code in.

Comment: But I don't know exactly where?!  Can you show me that?  The error message of PHP is present.

Comment: I think it it because target element hasn't any text that you trying to get it using `nodeValue`. I has only one `<img>`

Comment: I want to output the content.  So that <a>....</a>

I feel like he's not gonna find the div.

Comment: Just use `$doc->saveHtml($row)` instead of `$row->nodeValue`

Comment: @Mohammad, Thank you for your help. I implemented your proposal and finally achieved the result. I adjusted the first contribution accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Working version:**

Thanks to Mohammad.

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature,tv_movie&release_date=,2018'); //get the html returned from the following url

$doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

if(!empty($html)){ //if any html is actually returned

    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    //get all the h2's with an id
    $row = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 'lister-item-image') and contains(@class, 'float-left')]");

    if($row->length > 0){
        foreach($row as $row){
            echo $doc->saveHtml($row) . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```